# Unable to close OledbDataReader to Sybase Database in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sybase, data-access

I don't seem to be able to close the OledbDataReader object after reading data from it. Here is the relevant code -

```
Dim conSyBase As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Sybase.ASEOLEDBProvider.2;Server Name=xx.xx.xx.xx;Server Port Address=5000;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxxxx;User ID=xxxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxx;")

conSyBase.Open()

Dim cmdSyBase As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("MySQLStatement", conSyBase)
Dim drSyBase As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmdSyBase.ExecuteReader

Try

    While drSyBase.Read
     /*Do some stuff with the data here */

    End While

Catch ex As Exception

    NotifyError(ex, "Read failed.")

End Try

drSyBase.Close() /* CODE HANGS HERE */
conSyBase.Close()
drSyBase.Dispose()
cmdSyBase.Dispose()
conSyBase.Dispose()
```

The console application just hangs at the point at which I try to close the reader. Opening and closing a connection is not a problem, therefore does anyone have any ideas for what may be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer!

Before

```
drSyBase.Close()
```

You need to call the cancel method of the Command  object

```
cmdSyBase.Cancel()
```

I believe that this may be specific to Sybase databases

Answer (score 0):

This is a long-shot, but try moving your .Close() and .Dispose() lines in a Finally block of the Try.  Like this:

```
Dim conSyBase As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Sybase.ASEOLEDBProvider.2;Server Name=xx.xx.xx.xx;Server Port Address=5000;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxxxx;User ID=xxxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxx;")
conSyBase.Open()
Dim cmdSyBase As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("MySQLStatement", conSyBase)
Dim drSyBase As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmdSyBase.ExecuteReader
Try
  While drSyBase.Read
   /*Do some stuff with the data here */
  End While
Catch ex As Exception 
  NotifyError(ex, "Read failed.")
Finally
  drSyBase.Close() 
  conSyBase.Close()
  drSyBase.Dispose()
  cmdSyBase.Dispose()
  conSyBase.Dispose()
End Try
```

Comment: Hi Mikey, I tried putting the close and dispose lines wihtin a finally block, but this did not rectify the problem

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used VB.NET, but the most safe way to handle this in C# is to use a "**using**" statement.

It's like an **implicit try-catch** and it makes sure all resources are closed/cancelled and disposed when the "using" ends.

```
using (OleDb.OleDbConnection connection = new OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)) 
{
    DoDataAccessStuff();
} // Your resource(s) are killed, disposed and all that
```

**Update**: Found a link about [Using statement in VB.NET 2.0](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/fritz/archive/2005/04/28/7834.aspx), hope it helps.

```
Using conSyBase As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Sybase.ASEOLEDBProvider.2;Server Name=xx.xx.xx.xx;Server Port Address=5000;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxxxx;User ID=xxxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxx;"), _
     cmdSyBase As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("MySQLStatement", conSyBase) 

    conSyBase.Open()
    Dim drSyBase As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmdSyBase.ExecuteReader

    Try
        While drSyBase.Read()

            '...'

        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        NotifyError(ex, "Read failed.")
    End Try

    cmdSyBase.Cancel()
End Using
```